# switching off screen using power manager

Tags: android

I am a newbie to android programming. In this code, I have a button and when I hit the button, the screen should go off. Can anyone help me with this code?

When I press the button there is no action being performed and the screen is on even though I release it.

I have used permission in manifest file as below

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"
```

protected static final String TAG = null;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button powerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.powerButton);
    final PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    final PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(
            PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "powerButton");

    powerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressLint("Wakelock")
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                if (wakeLock != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Acquire full screen wake lock.");
                    wakeLock.acquire();

                }
                if (powerManager.isScreenOn()) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "Wakelock successfully acquired");

                } else {
                    Log.d("TAG", "Wackelock not acquired");
                }

                if (wakeLock.isHeld()) {
                    wakeLock.release();
                    Log.d("TAG", "wakelock released sucessfully");
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("onClick", e.getMessage());
            }

        }

    });

}
}
```

Please help me out.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Does the screen have to turn off for your purpose, or is it enough to dim the screen to dark?

Answer (score 0):

This is a [Sample](http://android.okhelp.cz/turn-screen-on-off-android-sample-code/) that will turn your screen off on button click. The action happens at  `mButtonStopListener`

```
public class Main extends Activity {
        private SensorManager mSensorManager;
        private PowerManager mPowerManager;
        private WindowManager mWindowManager;
        private WakeLock mWakeLock;
        private Button button;
        private TextView textView;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
try{
            // Get an instance of the SensorManager
            mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

            // Get an instance of the PowerManager
            mPowerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);

            // Get an instance of the WindowManager
            mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
            mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay();

            // Create a bright wake lock
            mWakeLock = mPowerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK, getClass()
                    .getName());

            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            button.setOnClickListener(mButtonStopListener);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("onCreate", e.getMessage());
        }
} // END onCreate

        View.OnClickListener mButtonStopListener = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    mWakeLock.release();
                    textView.setText("mWakeLock.release()");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("onPause",e.getMessage());
                }

            }
        };

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            /*
             * when the activity is resumed, we acquire a wake-lock so that the
             * screen stays on, since the user will likely not be fiddling with the
             * screen or buttons.
             */

            try {
                mWakeLock.acquire();
                textView.setText("mWakeLock.acquire()");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("onResume", e.getMessage());
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();

            // and release our wake-lock
            try {
                mWakeLock.release();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("onPause",e.getMessage());
            }
        }
}
```

Make sure to include

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.HARDWARE_TEST"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"></uses-permission>    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
```

This should work from API level 7 & up.

Comment: SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK is deprecated as of API16

Answer (score 0):

The `onClick` callback method will not be called until you release your finger from the `powerButton`. So when you pressed the button, there was no action being performed.